# How do I mock two fetches or one Promise and one fetch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, fetch-api

I am trying to test the loadAllProjects function.

The test fails at .then() with the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

I have also tried mocking the reponse of getHeadersWithToken() but could not get it to work.

Snookered on this one and would appreciate any help.

test:

```
    it('should create SET_ALL_PROJECTS action when fetching projects', () => {
        fetch
            .once(JSON.stringify([{ access_token: "12345" }]))
            .once(JSON.stringify({ name: "x" }))

        const expectedActions = [
            { type: "SET_ALL_PROJECTS", json: { name: "x" } },
        ]

        store.dispatch(actions.loadAllProjects.apply())
            .then(() => {     // FAILS HERE
                expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions)
            })

    });
```

code:

```
    export const getHeadersWithToken = () => {
        return fetch("/.auth/me", requestOptions)
            .then(parseResponseAndHandleErrors)
            .then(json => {
                const header = 'Bearer ' + json[0].access_token
                const applicationJsonHeaders = getJsonHeaders(header)
                return applicationJsonHeaders
            })
            .catch( error=> {
                console.error(error)
            })
    }

    export const loadAllProjects = () => {
        return (dispatch) => {
            getHeadersWithToken()
                .then(applicationJsonHeaders => {
                    const requestOptions = {
                        method: 'GET',
                        headers: applicationJsonHeaders,
                    };
                    return fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECTS_API_URL + "/projects", requestOptions)
                        .then(parseResponseAndHandleErrors)
                        .then(json => {
                            dispatch(setAllProjects(json))})
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.error(error)
                            dispatch(failedToLoadProjects(error))
                        });
                })
        }
    }
```

store used in test:

```
    const store = mockStore(Map(
        {
            allProjects: Map({
            }),
            currentProject: Map({

                authenticationData: Map({

                })
            })
        })

    );
```

Comment: Which `then()`?

Comment: store.dispatch(actions.loadAllProjects.apply())
        .then

Comment: where `store` is imported from?

Comment: I added the store to the question

Comment: Well, I'm kind of surprised this is working at all though, don't you have to provide a `done` callback to the `it` so it can know the test is complete?  See [Testing Asynchronous Code](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html).

Comment: The test worked before loadAllProjects() called getHeadersWithToken() and the headers were hardcoded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this is ever useful to anyone and in acknowledgment of Septastium's answer, I eventually changed the code to:

```
async getHeadersWithToken(requestType) {
    if (process.env.REACT_APP_RUNNING_LOCALLY==="true") {
        return {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        };
    }
    let result = await fetch("/.auth/me", this.requestOptions)
    let headers = result.json()
        .then( json => {
            const header = 'Bearer ' + json[0].access_token
            const applicationJsonHeaders = this.getJsonHeaders(header, requestType)
            return applicationJsonHeaders
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error)
        })
    return headers
}
```

---

```
export const loadAllProjects = () => {
    return async dispatch => {
        const authenticator = new Authenticator()
        let applicationJsonHeaders = await authenticator.getHeadersWithToken(constants.GET)
        let loggedInUser = await authenticator.getLoggedInUser()
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: applicationJsonHeaders,
        };
        return await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECTS_API_URL + "/projects", requestOptions)
            .then(response => {
                return parseResponseAndHandleErrors(response)
            })
            .then(json => dispatch(setAllProjects(json)))
            .then(()=> dispatch(setAuthenticationData(loggedInUser)))
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error)
                return dispatch(failedToLoadProjects(error))
            });
    }
}
```

---

and the test to:

```
const checkActionsWereDispatched = async (expectedActions, actionCreator) => {
    const store = mockStore(Map(
        {
        }),
    );
    store.dispatch(await actionCreator.apply()).then(() => {
        expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions)
    })
}

it('should create SET_ALL_PROJECTS action when fetching projects', async () => {
    fetch
        .once(JSON.stringify([{ access_token: "12345" }]))
        .once(JSON.stringify({ name: "x" }))
    const expectedActions = [
        { type: "SET_ALL_PROJECTS", json: { name: "x" } },
    ]
    checkActionsWereDispatched(expectedActions, actions.loadAllProjects)
});
```

As noted above I think Spetastium's version of the test is easier to read than mine and his article [here](https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee) was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What Redux middleware are you using for the async stuff? Make sure you set up the middleware when creating the store for testing.

Since i dont see that anywhere in your code above im gonna assume we are not using that middleware here.

Since loadAllProjects is a higher order function i would do this:

```
it('should create SET_ALL_PROJECTS action when fetching projects', (done) => {
    fetch
        .once(JSON.stringify([{ access_token: "12345" }]))
        .once(JSON.stringify({ name: "x" }))

    const expectedActions = [
        { type: "SET_ALL_PROJECTS", json: { name: "x" } },
    ]

    // Higher order function that returns a new function.
    const loadAllProjectsAsync = actions.loadAllProjects();

    // The function returned expects a dispatch from Redux as an argument.
    // It will do async work and when its done, it will call the provided dispatch.
    loadAllProjectsAsync(store.dispatch).then(() => {
       expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
       done();
    })

});
```

You also need to modify your code for loadAllProjects so that the inner function returns the promise:

```
export const loadAllProjects = () => {
return (dispatch) => {

    // You will need to return the promise in order for the test to be able to call .then() on it.
    return getHeadersWithToken()
        .then(applicationJsonHeaders => {
            const requestOptions = {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: applicationJsonHeaders,
            };
            return fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECTS_API_URL + "/projects", requestOptions)
                .then(parseResponseAndHandleErrors)
                .then(json => {
                    dispatch(setAllProjects(json))})
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error)
                    dispatch(failedToLoadProjects(error))
                });
        })
}}
```

Also, as already stated, you must tell the jest when the test is done if you are testing async stuff. Do this by letting your it call take `done` as a param and call that as a function after you have verified the outcome i the .then()

This was just a quick fix from my side. There still might be something im missing or some bugs in the code above, but you get the point.

Let me know if you have any follow up questions?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. In the end I changed the code itself (see next post). I do prefer your version of the test as it is much more readable.

Comment: No problem. Hope it works for you and that you are satisfied with the code :D